# How to use p6spy for standalone application that limits its JDBC drivers?

Tags: p6spy

I have a standalone 3rd party application working with Oracle database and I need to troubleshoot its DB queries. And I don't have access to its source code (nor desire to decompile it :-) ).
Its DB connection configuration has several separate parameters:

- Driver: `oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver`
- JDBC URL: `jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl`
- User name & password

But I can't change driver as application is checking for a list of supported drivers and just refuse to start if I put `com.p6spy.engine.spy.P6SpyDriver` into the driver parameter.

So can p6spy still be used in this case? If not, is there any other way to trace application DB access from application's end (I'm aware of Oracle tracing, that would be my next step if this won't work)?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use P6Spy in [Datasource way](https://p6spy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration.html#datasource-way)